# How do I complete the third speedstar race?

Tags: nier-automata

The third Speedstar race in the City Ruins has the blue flying Machine fly over the gap the Engels made during the main story.

I can't see a way for me to quickly scale up the buildings if I am to follow the machine underneath, but if I go around, I seem to take too much time as I have tried repeatedly dashing and the sprint run after a dash and both of these were while I was using enough Movement Speed Up chips that I received a prompt saying the maximum speed increase is 20%.

How do I complete this third race?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This video](https://youtu.be/lnARbeoHJ1s) lays out the path you'll need to take to win this race. You will also want to equip as many Movement Speed Up chips as possible, like you've been doing, though I seem to recall beating this without maxing my movement speed.

In a nutshell, you'll just want to jump down then run straight ahead, hugging the left wall. There will eventually be a small jump you'll need to make. After the jump, repeatedly evade towards the finish, because I don't think you'll have enough time to start sprinting before the end of the race.

Comment: Also, you can use `Overclock 6` chip and evade attacks from small enemies to gain 5-6 seconds of slow-motion, repeat as needed.